# Show spinner while loading image in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, spinner, loader

In the following **example** I made a simple image spinner loader with **Vue.js**:

https:// jsfiddle.net/Tenarius/g2chd796/8/

The problem is that, especially with larger images, the image often loads **piece by piece**. That doesn't look good to the user.

[image]

---

The picture should only be displayed when it is fully loaded. As long as the image is not fully loaded, the spinner should be displayed.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image will be emitting an event `load` which will be fired once the image is loaded.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    imgsrc: "",
    btntext: "Show Image",
    isLoaded: false,
    isLoading: false
  },
  methods: {
    loaded() {
        this.isLoaded = true;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    toggleimg: function(){
        if (this.imgsrc == "") {
      this.isLoaded =  false;
      this.isLoading = true;
            this.imgsrc = "https://images2.alphacoders.com/103/1039991.jpg"
        this.btntext = "Hide Image"
      }else{
      this.imgsrc = ""
      this.btntext = "Show Image"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.loading {
  background: transparent url('https://miro.medium.com/max/882/1*9EBHIOzhE1XfMYoKz1JcsQ.gif') center no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Image Loader Spinner</h2>
  <button @click="toggleimg">{{ btntext }}</button>
  <div v-if="isLoading" class="loading"></div>
  <img v-show="isLoaded" :src="imgsrc" width="400" @load="loaded">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `new Image()`

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'https://images2.alphacoders.com/103/1039991.jpg';
myImage.onload = () => {
    this.imgsrc = myImage.src
}      
this.imgsrc = 'https://miro.medium.com/max/882/1*9EBHIOzhE1XfMYoKz1JcsQ.gif'
this.btntext = "Hide Image"
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/udrwtzcs/)